# Submodel in the sameview MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a Model call Customer like this

```
public class Customer : Person
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss}")]
    [Display(Name = "Create Date")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to include the subModel "Notes" in the same view.
because I would like to open a page with Customer details but also able to Add, edit, read all the notes in the same page.

I try to use 
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes)
how ever its not possible.

so I create a viewModel

```
public class CustomerNotesModel
{
    public Customer Customers { get; set; }
    public Note Note { get; set; }
}
```

but this throws me an error when I try to click "details" or the page.
which return a customer to a page type of

> argument type 'Model.customers' is not assignable to model type
>   'viewModels.customerNotesModel' mvc..

sorry, I'm very new to it and i really i did try hell hard to find it out unfortunately there wont be enough time for me. 
anyone has any Idear?
as long as im able to ADD a note of the current Customer in the same page is fine. Thanks

Comment: Are you using view model in your view?

Comment: please add current code for view and controller here